# add label ...on Browser or flashPlayer in C# wpf

Tags: wpf

1. I can't load the controls:FlashPlayer in C# WPF on the computer 64 byte
   add it's working on computer 32 byte
2. How can I put label or command on Browser or FlashPlayer 
   I cant do FrontToBack or GoFront ...
   Do you know How can I do Front to back ????

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a 64bit Flash Player for Windows. Your WPF program must run in 32bit mode. I don't understand your second question.